# Widget preview with pre-3.0 sdk target

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

Is it possible to add a widget preview for an app targeting an sdk pre-3.0, so that post 3.0 devices get a preview image?

Answer (score 0):

It should work by default. Pre-3.0 devices will ignore the `android:previewImage` attribute.

If for some reason you find that devices are complaining about that attribute, create two versions of your XML metadata file, one in `res/xml/` and one in `res/xml-v11/`, and only put the preview image in the second copy. Android will choose the right edition of your metadata at runtime based on the device version.

Comment: I also thought it should work this way, but in fact it does not. Even when putting the XML file in `res/xml-v11` I get `Type error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'previewImage' in package 'android'` in Eclipse.

Comment: @sschuberth: You need to set your build target (Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) to API Level 11 or higher.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize I need to set the target SDK in both AndroidManifest.xml *and* Eclipse's project.properties. Thanks!